# What is the exact difference between the particles が and は?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-が, subjects, topic

I understand that が is meant to mark the subject and that は is the particle placed after the topic, but still after a heck ton of research, I haven't been able to truly comprehend the meaning of both these particles, and in particular, the difference between the subject and the topic of a sentence. For example, I understand why you would place は after 私 in a sentence like, "私は卵を食べた", but what if there is a sentence like "today, I will eat fish", would you translate that as "kyo wa, watashi wa sakana wo tabemasu" (I know that usually "わたし" is omitted from the sentence, but for other instances, I keep it. But is "kyo" the subject? Please explain to me!

Comment: The subject is the person/thing that does the action of a verb so, no, kyo is not the subject. The subject in that sentence would be 'I', but it has been promoted to a topic in your example. Below is the link we normally give for this question. Please read it and feel free to ask a more specific question if you still have problems (you will. It's a very involved and complicated subject). https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/22/whats-the-difference-between-wa-%e3%81%af-and-ga-%e3%81%8c

Comment: You may also find this series helpful. It's a bit weird and unconventional but I think it makes some helpful points. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCkdmU8hGK4Fg3LghTVtKltQ/videos

Comment: Hi Amito, welcome to JLSE! Please look at the link that user3856370 posted, and other "は and が" questions already asked on the site. I've voted to close your question for now, as it's quite broad and I think answered by the link provided, but if after reading the answers you have a more specific question, please ask that question in a new post :) Thanks and welcome again to JLSE!